# Fill for svg/path not applying

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, next.js, tailwind-css

I have svg that I apply 2 colors through props one for background works and the other for fill doesn't. I'm using Next.js.

```
export default function Divider({
  topColor,
  bottomColor,
}: {
  topColor: string;
  bottomColor: string;
}) {
  return (
    <svg
      data-name="Layer 1"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      viewBox="0 0 1200 120"
      preserveAspectRatio="none"
      className={`bg-${bottomColor}`}
    >
      <path
        d="M321.39,56.44c58-10.79,114.16-30.13,172-41.86,82.39-16.72,168.19-17.73,250.45-.39C823.78,31,906.67,72,985.66,92.83c70.05,18.48,146.53,26.09,214.34,3V0H0V27.35A600.21,600.21,0,0,0,321.39,56.44Z"
        className={`fill-${topColor}`}
      ></path>
    </svg>
  );
}
```

```
<Divider topColor="cyan-950" bottomColor="slate-50" />
```

[DividerIMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7xaz.png)

Strange thing is I can see class being applied in dev tools `class="fill-cyan-950"` but as you can see in the image above it doesn't show on the screen (it's black should be dark blue/green). If I do it explicitly in the code without props it works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider passing full class names in the props like:

```html
<Divider topColor="fill-cyan-950" bottomColor="bg-slate-50" />
```

```
<svg
  …
  className={bottomColor}
>
  <path
    …
    className={topColor}
  ></path>
</svg>
```